# Lack of titles for esteemed Lubavitch rabbis

Tags: minhag, chabad

What is the reason for Chabad Lubavitch using very basic titles for great rabbis and scholars.

Most Mashpiim in lubavitch yeshivas are simply called "Reb" with no other prefix and usually no suffix (aside for their name)

[Here](https://crownheights.info/notices/738384/bde-reb-yoel-kahan-91-obm/#:%7E:text=BDE%3A-,Reb%20Yoel%20Kahan,-%2C%2091%2C%20OBM) is an example, announcing the death of the foremost teacher and scholar of lubavitch chasidus,

Rabbi Yoel Kahan Z"L was simply called "Reb Yoel"

[This](https://anash.org/a-master-of-all-trades-2/#:%7E:text=Amud%20Yomi-,REB%20MEILECH,-%3A%20A%20MASTER%20OF) is another example. Rabbi Elimelech Zweibel Z"L, Head Mashpia of Lubavitch Yeshivah, was simply known as "Reb Meilech"

([This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menachem_Mendel_Futerfas#:%7E:text=known%20informally%20as%20Reb%20Mendel%2C) and [this](https://chabadinfo.com/news/lets-farbreng-reb-avraham-pariz/#:%7E:text=Let%E2%80%99s%20Farbreng%3B-,Reb%20Avraham%20Pariz,-One%20of%20the) are further examples)

Whats this all about?

Comment: @RabbiKaii i added another example

Comment: ALL Mashpiim in Lubavitch Yeshivas are called  "Reb". A rov is usually called Rabbi, and very rarely is "Shlita" used, if its used, its usual for an older Rabbi or a member of Beis Din.

Comment: Perhaps the better question is why other groups call everyone and his uncle "the great esteemed leader of our generation" or the like

Comment: The Rebbe is often called "The Rebbe Shlita".

Comment: עליהם נאמר ״גדול מרבן שמו״

Comment: @Shmuel Yea, thats for a different discussion lol

Comment: Rav Moshe Feinstein zt"l is also sometimes called "Reb Moshe". Although I do not know if this is applied in a broader public.

Comment: Within Lubavitcher circles "Rav" would be reserved for a Rabbi who is usually involved with halacha.

Comment: As @DoubleAA said, methinks the profusion of honorifics today doth protest too much the absence of true greatness. As for why Chabad avoided that trend, I think it's a combination of fraternalism derived from an emphasis on ahavas yisroel and a shared sense of *bittul* before the Rebbe.

Comment: @shmosel can you please "re-word" and enter your comment in answer form.

Answer (score 3):

I think that chabad avoid kavod.
the bitul is a quality that the chassidous praises.
moreover at chabad one seeks proximity with his mashpia perhaps the fact of not calling him by too many names of kavod allows the chassid to feel closer

Answer (score 2):

The Rebbe explains (brought down in Toras Menachem 5743 Chelek 1 page 543), that being that a true student is constantly reviewing the teachings of his Rebbe, and as the Yerushalmi (Kiddushin 1:7) says, that when one reviews a teaching, he must picture as if the master of that teaching stands in front of him, it would therefore be considered inappropriate to give excessive titles to one of his students, like the Gemara (Shabbos 56a) says that Uriyah Hachiti was Chayav Missah, because he referred to Dovid’s general Yoav as “my master” in front of Dovid Hamelech